# Swift PFFile Exception when encoding with aCoder

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pffile

I am trying to encode a PFFile and save it persistently but it returns an Exception:

The class:

```
import UIKit

import Parse

class Usuario: PFObject, PFSubclassing, NSCoding {

    //MARK: Propriedades
    //O NSManaged é para o PFObject
    @NSManaged var nome: String?
    @NSManaged var foto: PFFile?
    @NSManaged var dataNascimento: Date?
    @NSManaged var numeroTelefone: String?
    @NSManaged var pais: PaisCodigo?
    @NSManaged var telefoneE164: String?

    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Usuario"
    }


    //Isto é para NSObject e NSCoding
    override init() {

        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init()

        self.nome = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "nome") as? String
        self.foto = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "foto") as? PFFile
        self.dataNascimento = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "dataNascimento") as? Date
        self.numeroTelefone = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "numeroTelefone") as? String
        self.pais = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "pais") as? PaisCodigo
        self.telefoneE164 = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "telefoneE164") as? String
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

        if let nomeUsuario = nome {
            aCoder.encode(nomeUsuario, forKey: "nome")
        }

        if let fotoUsuario = foto {
            //The problems happens here
            aCoder.encode(fotoUsuario, forKey: "foto")
        }

        if let dataNascimentoUsuario = dataNascimento {
            aCoder.encode(dataNascimentoUsuario, forKey: "dataNascimento")
        }

        if let numeroTelefoneUsuario = numeroTelefone {
            aCoder.encode(numeroTelefoneUsuario, forKey: "numeroTelefone")
        }

        if let paisUsuario = pais {
            aCoder.encode(paisUsuario, forKey: "pais")
        }

        if let telefoneE164Usuario = telefoneE164 {
            aCoder.encode(telefoneE164Usuario, forKey: "telefoneE164")
        }
    }
}
```

I try to save the data with this method:

The contatos object is an array of Usuario (the class above)

```
func fazerCacheContatos() {

        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

        let contatosIDoPartyCodificados: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: contatos)

        userDefaults.set(contatosCodificados, forKey: "cacheContatos")

        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }
```

When I run the app I receive this exception:

`-[PFFile encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170e513d0`

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFFile encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170e513d0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was transforming the object to UIImage to encode and to PFFile after decoding as the code below:

```
import UIKit

import Parse

class Usuario: PFObject, PFSubclassing, NSCoding {

    //MARK: Propriedades
    //O NSManaged é para o PFObject
    @NSManaged var nome: String?
    @NSManaged var foto: PFFile?
    @NSManaged var dataNascimento: Date?
    @NSManaged var numeroTelefone: String?
    @NSManaged var pais: PaisCodigo?
    @NSManaged var telefoneE164: String?

    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Usuario"
    }


    //Isto é para NSObject e NSCoding
    override init() {

        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init()

        self.nome = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "nome") as? String

        let image = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "foto") as? UIImage
        if let fotoImage = image {
            self.foto = PFFile(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(fotoImage)!)
        }

        self.dataNascimento = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "dataNascimento") as? Date
        self.numeroTelefone = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "numeroTelefone") as? String
        self.pais = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "pais") as? PaisCodigo
        self.telefoneE164 = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "telefoneE164") as? String
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

        if let nomeUsuario = nome {
            aCoder.encode(nomeUsuario, forKey: "nome")
        }

        if let fotoUsuario = foto {
            do {
                let dataImage = try fotoUsuario.getData()

                let image = UIImage(data: dataImage)!

                aCoder.encode(image, forKey: "foto")
            } catch {
                //Erro
            }
        }

        if let dataNascimentoUsuario = dataNascimento {
            aCoder.encode(dataNascimentoUsuario, forKey: "dataNascimento")
        }

        if let numeroTelefoneUsuario = numeroTelefone {
            aCoder.encode(numeroTelefoneUsuario, forKey: "numeroTelefone")
        }

        if let paisUsuario = pais {
            aCoder.encode(paisUsuario, forKey: "pais")
        }

        if let telefoneE164Usuario = telefoneE164 {
            aCoder.encode(telefoneE164Usuario, forKey: "telefoneE164")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `PFFile` class does not support the `NSCoding` protocol. If `PFFile` is your own class, then you can solve this by adding `NSCoding` support to it. If `PFFile` is a class you're getting from a third-party for which you do not have the source code, then you will have to find some other way to store the information needed to reconstitute the `PFFile` later on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.